# Good tool for converting mssql queries to mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I found alot of question on stack about converting mysql to mssql, but i would like to convert it otherwise.

From mssql server to mysql.

is there a (free) tool for this to do that without connecting to the databases?
i have an sql query dump and i want to convert that by putting that code in an tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably best off doing this yourself to ensure everything is correct rather than relying on a third party tool (Also the additional benefit of understanding the differences between the two pieces of code).  However you could use this SQL to MySQL tool:

http://download.cnet.com/SQL-To-MySQL-Converter/3000-10254_4-75693763.html

Comment: Thanks. and i already thought about this. but because i'm new to mssql i found it useful to ask this :)

Comment: @KeesSonnema okay cool. IMO you shouldn't have trouble converting simple SELECTS/INSERTS and Update statements, only when TSQL is used it would become more tricky.  Hope this helped.

Comment: yes. the most code are INSERTS and SELECTS but it's always worth a try to do it myself :)